# Where are default Plasma 5 settings stored?

Tags: configuration, kde, plasma

On a distributed System (NFS root), I'd like to change the way the desktop
appears to users that have never logged in on the system before, i.e. have no settings set.
I'd like to change some desktop symbols, change the default activity to desktop symbols and switch from the simple program launcher to kickoff.

How would I do that?

Comment: Isn't Kickoff already the default launcher for Plasma 5? I suspect that the pertinent file is `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`. Why don't you create a new user, log into KDE then make your changes? Then create another new user, log into KDE, then diff the two home directories. You might need to run `kbuildsycoca5` or something similar after modifying the config files.

Comment: The file you mentioned is indeed the right one, but on a per-user basis. I want to set the defaults a user gets when he first logs in.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the distinction. Each user's preferences *are* stored on a per-user basis.

Comment: Exactly. I want to know where the global/default/system settings are stored.

Comment: Ahhhh… I understand now. I'm really not sure where that might be. Perhaps you could ask on the KDE forums. They are usually very helpful.

Answer (score 12):

Since plasma5's modularization the config files are not saved in a single folder anymore. You will find different files in `~/.config` (typically ending with .rc) and some other parts in `~/.local` (e.g. plasma themes).

The plasmoids are saved in "~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc". It also saves the folder view desktop and the kickoff launcher.

A template folder for new users is located under `/etc/skel/`. The contained files will be copied to the users home directory while creating a new user.

Comment: There are no default plasma config files in /etc/skel. So, where does plasma5 and its plasmoids get the default config from if there is no config in ~?

Comment: It is written on the first login. You can start with a clean/fresh user, log in, do the adjustments you like, log out and copy the configuration files over to skel.

Comment: What about settings associated to Plasma activities? Where are those settings stored?

Answer (score 1):

I have found various KDE global configs in the following location when I was trying to kill that painful 30 seconds timeout delay at the logout screen during the MX Linux KDE dev cycle
/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop

Answer (score 0):

I've created a "template" config folder structure. This way:

1. Created new user.
2. Loged in as the new user.
3. Made some tweaks and configurations.
4. Loged out and copied thus created folder structure somewhere safe.

Now when I create new user the first thing BEFORE his first login is to copy this folder structure into his home folder (and change the ownership and permissions). This way the new user has some predefined settings. You may even put this skeleton folder in version control so you can manage future changes.